# How can I use The Cocotron to build a simple app for Windows?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, windows, macos, cocotron

I'm having trouble getting [The Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org) to work. The web site has some instructions. Though, these are outdated and vague. Can anyone explain to me how to use The Cocotron to build a simple test app for Windows?

What I'd like to do is take the trivial Cocoa app that you get if you go to Xcode and create a new Cocoa application project, and then build that app for Windows.

Note: Yes, there are other SO questions about using Cocotron, but all are years old and none are relevant.

1. Start with Xcode 7.3 and OS X 10.11.5 because these are the current versions of the developer tools and operating system.
2. Create a simple Cocoa app by going to File > New Project and choosing "Cocoa Application." I want to start by porting this absolutely trivial app.
3. Installing the Cocotron is tricky due to outdated documentation. I've outlined the issues with this process [here](http://andrewfox.postach.io/post/building-the-cocotron). I was able to get frameworks and the cross-compiler installed.
4. Follow the documentation to configure a new target for building on Windows. Unfortunately, the documentation is incorrect and outdated. Many of the settings it mentions such as "GCC_FAST_OBJC_DISPATCH" as simply not listed in Xcode at all. I've followed the documentation to the letter where it is possible to do so, ignored the build settings which do not exist, and tried to make intelligent guesses for the rest.
5. Results: When I do this and build my new target for Windows, I get a plethora of errors. These are listed on that blog post I linked above. The errors are mostly along the lines of "unrecognized command line option."